# Need help formulating an event scheduling problem involving multiple clients and class types

Tags: combinatorics, linear-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I run training classes. A "B" class, a "C" class and an "Adv" advanced class.

B classes run every saturday, take 3 hours, and have a maximum 4 clients.
C classes follow B classes and take 2 hours. There are 3 of them, sequentially, one a week (although this frequency could be increased). Max 4 clients.
Adv classes follow C classes and occur every 6 weeks, take 2 hrs. There are 8 of them, 1 class every 6 weeks. Max 4 clients.

Time available on saturdays for classes is 8 hours. Could go to 10 hrs maximum, but ideally no more than 8 hrs.
C classes ideally run on saturdays, but could also run on mondays (max time allocated 4 hours).
Adv classes can run on mondays, fridays (max time 4 hours) and saturdays.

I'm trying to figure out an optimum use of time that has the most clients progressing through from B to C to Adv.